# Error when I try to make clone of HN in Windows 7: 'rm' is not recognized

Tags: lisp, arc-lisp

I have downloaded Arc 3.1 and Racket to my Windows 7 machine.
I have solved many errors as instructed in http://www.arclanguage.org/item?id=12397 
Now when I enter `(nsv)` the following error occurs and `localhost:8080` comes out blank:

```
arc> (nsv)
'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
load items:
ranking stories.
user break

=== context ===
C:\arc3.1\ac.scm:1031:20
 gs1259

ready to serve port 8080
user break

=== context ===
C:\arc3.1\ac.scm:1031:20
 gs1259

**open-input-file: cannot open input file: "C:/dev/urandom" (The system cannot fin
d the path specified.; errno=3)**

=== context ===
 rand-string
 new-fnid
 fnid
 flink
zz
zz
zz
 gs2061
 cache
 newspage
 gs2059
 gs1059
 handle-request-thread
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there's something wrong with your cygwin setup.  It can't find `rm`.  Should the cygwin binaries be in your path or something?

Also, cygwin should probably be translating `/dev/urandom`, since `C:/dev/urandom` doesn't make sense

Comment: I'd try installing cygwin, that might just solve your problem

Comment: i came across this http://arclanguage.org/item?id=12400 , but actually didn't get how to solve.

Comment: Using cygwin solved the above issue.but,now when i run mzscheme -f as.scm
it never returns to prompt(like loop).when i use mzscheme -m -f as.scm
it shows "main: not defined or required into the top-level environment" message

Comment: Glad you solved the first part, but I@m afraid I don't know what to suggest next.  probably best to start a new question.