# Error when I try to make clone of HN in Windows 7: main: not defined

Tags: racket, arc-lisp

I have downloaded Arc 3.1 and Racket in my Windows 7 machine, and [solved many errors while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517645/error-when-i-try-to-make-clone-of-hn-in-windows) proceeding. But still when I run `mzscheme -f as.scm` it never returns to the prompt (as if there was an infinite loop). When I use `mzscheme -m -f as.scm`, it shows

> main: not defined or required into the top-level environment

and `localhost:8080` comes out blank.

Comment: Have you already looked at Anarki?  Supposed to be actively developed: https://github.com/nex3/arc

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Arc uses an old version of Racket.
The page http://arclanguage.org/install
says to use version 372 of MzScheme.

You can download version 372 here:
    http://download.plt-scheme.org/all-versions.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also run the prompt without the "-m" option.

> mzscheme -f as.scm

There is a little bit more info on the [arclanguage wiki](https://sites.google.com/site/arclanguagewiki/getting-started/install-arc).

Answer (score 0):

You can run Arc 3.1 on top of Racket; you no longer need mzscheme. You can start Arc up with `racket -f as.scm`.